# How Pass Data to Parent Component React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and I am developing my final year project using it.
I am facing an issue when trying to get the value of a child component.
I made my own component out of DateTimePicker (displaying only the date), and then I am using this date picker in another screen.
When selecting a new value using the picker I want to store this new value in the parent state.
I did some research online and found that I need to pass the data from the child to the parent. I tried doing that but now I am getting the below error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.onSelectDate')]
```

You can find my code below:
Parent component:

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard} from "react-native";
import RadioForm, {RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';

import AppDatePicker from '../components/AppDatePicker';
import AppTimePicker from '../components/AppTimePicker';

var radio_field_type = [
  {label: 'Natural Turf', value: 0 },
  {label: 'Artificial Turf', value: 1 }
];

class CreateGameScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gameDate: ""
    }
  }
  handleNewDate(dateValue) {
    this.setState({gameDate: dateValue});
  }
  render() {
    return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
  onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>
            <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>Create Game</Text>
        </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{margin: 3}}>
    <AppDatePicker style={styles.pickerButton}
      onSelectDate={this.handleNewDate}
    ></AppDatePicker>
    <Text>{this.state.gameDate}</Text>
    </View> 
  </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
  }}

export default CreateGameScreen;
```

And here is the child code:

```
import {View, Button, Platform, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export const AppDatePicker = (props) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(1598051730000));
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleOnChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    this.props.onSelectDate(currentDate);
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode('date');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker} style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black', flexDirection: 'row',   height: 40}}>
        <Text style={{marginBottom: 6, fontSize: 16,marginLeft: 10, alignSelf: 'center'}}>Please select the game date</Text>
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar" size={35} color="black"/>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {show && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={date}
          mode={mode}
          is24Hour={true}
          display="default"
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
      )}
    </View>
    
  );
};

export default AppDatePicker;
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.onSelectDate(currentDate)` should be `props.onSelectDate(currentDate)` in the child component. Only use `this` in class components. Your child component is a functional component.

**Edit**

You will also have to bind your `handleNewDate(dateValue)` in the constructor. Add this in your constructor:

```
this.handleNewDate = this.handleNewDate.bind(this)
```

or you can also declare your function as an arrow function, like below:

```
handleNewDate = (dateValue) => {
    // your logic
  };
```

Then when rendering the date in the `<Text>` component. Make sure the date value is of type string and not Date type. Because RN `<Text>` component only accepts string values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like the issue got solved. I am still not able to see the selected date in the Text component below the date picker.
I am still getting a Possible unhandled promise rejection. This time it says: this.setState is not a function (in this.setState({gameDate: dateValue}), this.setState is undefined

Comment: @ymho I've updated my answer. Try it out and let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue. However, sadly other issues surfaced. Now the picker is getting displayed again after dismissing it. But I will work on the new issues and try to fix them. 
Thank you for your response